# Data not updating correctly with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, knockout.js

I just started with knockout.js a week ago, so hopefully this is something easy. I've spent  about 5 hours searching Google and this site and none of the suggestions I've seen seem to work. I've tried changing pagedPlayerList to just playerList to remove that part of the code as an issue.

I have this code showing some data with knockout.js

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Attack</th>
                        <th>Defense</th>
                        <th>Level</th>
                        <th>IPH</th>
                        <th>Syndicate</th>
                        <th>Last Modified</th>
                        <th style="width: 100px; text-align:right;" />
                    </tr>
                </thead>
               <tbody data-bind=" template:{name:playerTemplateToUse, foreach: pagedPlayerList }"></tbody>
            </table>

            <ul class="pagination">
                <li data-bind="css: { disabled: pageIndex() === 0 }"><a href="#" data-bind="click: previousPage">&laquo;</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="pagination" data-bind="foreach: allPlayerPages">
                <li data-bind="css: { active: $data.pageNumber === ($root.pageIndex() + 1) }"><a href="#" data-bind="text: $data.pageNumber, click: function() { $root.moveToPage($data.pageNumber-1); }"></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="pagination">
              <li data-bind="css: { disabled: pageIndex() === maxPlayerPageIndex() }"><a href="#" data-bind="click: nextPlayerPage">&raquo;</a></li>
            </ul>

            <script id="itemsPlayerTmpl" type="text/html">
               <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: att"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: def"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: lvl"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: iph"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: synd_name"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: $root.lastModDate(last_modified)"></td>
                    <td class="buttons">
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-bind="click: $root.edit" href="#" title="edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-bind="click: $root.removePlayer" href="#" title="remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </script>

            <script id="editPlayerTmpl" type="text/html">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
                    <td><input data-bind="value: name"/></td>
                    <td><input size="8" data-bind="value: att"/></td>
                    <td><input size="8" data-bind="value: def"/></td>
                    <td><input size="3" data-bind="value: lvl"/></td>
                    <td><input size="8" data-bind="value: iph"/></td>
                    <td>
                       <select data-bind="options: $root.syndList, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: synd_id, selectedOptions: 'synd_id', optionsCaption: 'Please select...'"></select>
                    </td>

                    <td data-bind="text: $root.lastModDate(last_modified)"></td>
                    <td class="buttons">
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-bind="click: $root.savePlayer" href="#" title="save"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-bind="click: $root.cancel" href="#" title="cancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </script>
```

It works perfectly when the page is loaded. The problem is, I want to have the data updated automatically every 2 minutes, and when I load the data in the display isn't updated.

Here is the relevant section of javascript

```
        self.playerList = ko.observableArray();
        <?php if(isset($playerlist)) { ?>
            self.playerList(jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo addslashes($playerlist); ?>'));
        <?php } ?>

        self.lastModDate = function(data){
            var myDate = new Date(data * 1000);
            var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
            var month = months[myDate.getMonth()];
            var date = myDate.getDate();
            var year = myDate.getFullYear();
            var time = date+', '+month+' '+year;
            return time;
        }
        // ALL PLAYERS TAB       
        self.addPlayer = function () {
            var newItem = new Player();
            self.playerList.push(newItem);
            self.selectedItem(newItem);
            self.moveToPage(self.maxPlayerPageIndex());
        };
        self.removePlayer = function (item) {
            if (item.id) {
                if (confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this item?')) {
                    $.post('<?php echo base_url('front/deleteplayer'); ?>', item).complete(function (result) {
                        if(result = '1'){
                            toastr.success("The player has been removed.", "");
                            self.playerList.remove(item);
                            if (self.pageIndex() > self.maxPlayerPageIndex()) {
                                self.moveToPage(self.maxPlayerPageIndex());
                            }
                        } else {
                            toastr.error("There was a problem removing the player", "");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            else {
                self.list.remove(item);
                if (self.pageIndex() > self.maxPlayerPageIndex()) {
                    self.moveToPage(self.maxPlayerPageIndex());
                }
            }
        };
        self.savePlayer = function () {
            var item = self.selectedItem();
            $.post('<?php echo base_url('front/saveplayer'); ?>', item, function (result) {
                console.log(item);
                toastr.success("Your changes have been saved.", "");
                self.selectedItem(null);
            });

        };
        self.pagedPlayerList = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            var size = self.pageSize();
            var start = self.pageIndex() * size;
            return self.playerList().slice(start, start + size);
        });
        self.maxPlayerPageIndex = ko.dependentObservable(function (list) {
            return Math.ceil(self.playerList().length / self.pageSize()) - 1;
        });
        self.nextPlayerPage = function () {
            if (self.pageIndex() < self.maxPlayerPageIndex()) {
                self.pageIndex(self.pageIndex() + 1);
            }
        };
        self.allPlayerPages = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            var pages = [];
            for (i = 0; i <= self.maxPlayerPageIndex() ; i++) {
                pages.push({ pageNumber: (i + 1) });
            }
            return pages;
        });
        self.playerTemplateToUse = function (item) {
            return self.selectedItem() === item ? 'editPlayerTmpl' : 'itemsPlayerTmpl';
        };
        // END ALL PLAYERS TAB

        self.edit = function (item) {
            self.selectedItem(item);
            self.currentSynd(item.synd_id);
        };

        self.cancel = function () {
            self.selectedItem(null);
        };
        self.previousPage = function () {
            if (self.pageIndex() > 0) {
                self.pageIndex(self.pageIndex() - 1);
            }
        };
        self.moveToPage = function (index) {
            self.pageIndex(index);
        };
```

Then this is the binding/update code

```
    // SELF UPDATING DATA
    update = function() {
        siteModel.updatePlayerList();
        console.log(siteModel.playerList);
    }

    var siteModel = new siteModel();
    window.setInterval(update,60000);
    ko.applyBindings(siteModel);
```

This is the updatePlayerList function

```
        self.updatePlayerList = function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'<?php echo base_url('front/listplayers'); ?>',
                success:function(data) {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    self.playerList = (obj);
                }
            });
        }
```

The first time updatePlayerList fires this is an excerpt of what the server is returning:

```
[{"id":"19","name":"AlDavisJR","att":"818741","def":"895287","lvl":"227","iph":"2804866","synd_id":"9","last_modified":"1384284327","synd_name":"FIGHT CLUB"},{"id":"15","name":"aLEX","att":"95748","def":"112386","lvl":"227","iph":"16033","synd_id":"15","last_modified":"1384240593","synd_name":"iron"}]
```

But the console.log(self.playerList); shows a blank value. The second and any subsequent times it runs console.log shows the correct data.

The problem is the table always shows the data that's loaded when the page is first loaded. If I modify the database the ajax call gets the new data back but the site isn't uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of code, so there might be more going on, but the first thing I spot, is that you're updating the data wrong in your self.updatePlayerList function.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
self.playerList = (obj); // This assigns obj to self.playerList, overwriting the observableArray
```

Instead do

```
self.playerList(obj); // This keeps the observable intact, and assigns obj as it's new internal value
```

Let me know if that solved it for you!

**Edit:**

In addition, the reason your console.log is blank the first time, is because updatePlayerList is an asynchronous function (because your ajax call executes asynchronously). So the ajax function will be called, and WHILE it's retrieving the data, you already output the value of your observableArray to the console. Instead, you'll want to wait until the success-callback fires, and log to the console there to check if the value is correct.

Another tip that might be helpful: when you log observables to the console, you'll not get to see the actual value of the observable. The helper functions `ko.toJS(yourObservableHere)` and `ko.toJSON(yourObservableHere)` are very helpful for retrieving the actual values of your (nested) observables. The first one makes a plain javascript object out of whatever you put in (removing the observable wrappers), the second does the same, but outputs it all to a JSON string. This can be useful for debugging in the UI (e.g. `<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(yourViewModel)"></div>`

Comment: I knew the first time I asked a question here it would be something really stupid. That did the trick. Thank you.